# shell script to comment out or uncomment a line - testing

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing, grep, sed

Trying to remove a `#` sign from a single line in a file. The line is currently

```
#/usr/bin/tvservice -o
```

```bsh
if [[ '$grep tvservice /etc/rc.local' =~ ^# ]] ;
then sed -i '/^#.* tvservice /s/^#//' /etc/rc.local ;
else echo 1 fi
```

Trying to test if this command will work before I add it to a script. When I run it I get a `>` symbol and have to stop execution with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Am I not passing a string to `grep` correctly or what? I'm fairly new to this.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you test **without** sed's `-i` flag first - or use a local copy of the `rc.local` file.

You don't *need* to test for the string's presence, but if you do, then the correct way to substitute grep's *output* would be `"$(grep tvservice /etc/rc.local)"` - the way you have written it tests the literal string `$grep tvservice /etc/rc.local`

However, a better way IMHO would be to grep for the whole pattern and use grep's exit status directly, avoiding the shell regex test altogether:

```
if grep -q '^#.*tvservice' /etc/rc.local; then 
  sed -i '/^#.*tvservice/ s/^#//' /etc/rc.local
else 
  echo 1
fi
```

(I removed the spaces around the pattern, since your sample text doesn't have them).

Comment: Meh, just a minute faster than me...

Comment: I ran the command in this form and am getting 2 as output and then nothing. It doesn't really exit the script properly, any clues ? if grep -q '^#/*tvservice' /etc/rc.local; then
        echo 1
        sed -i '/^#.*tvservice/ s/^#//' /etc/rc.local
else
        echo 2
        sed -e '/tvservice/ s/^#*/#/'
fi

Comment: This is the state of the file currently
{code}

#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#Disable HDMI

#/usr/bin/tvservice -o


exit 0
{code}

Comment: I saw for second sed I didn't give it a file to edit. Fixed it the command runs and exits out but I get the "2" as output still which means that it skips the "then" where it's supposed to remove the # from that line.